# Make [mongocsharpdriver] a synonym for [mongodb-csharp]

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Both [mongocsharpdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongocsharpdriver) and [mongodb-csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-csharp) refer to the same C# driver  for MongoDB.

I have suggested a synonym, but I don't know how long it will take to be approved.